# a sub routine is not executing from another thread

Tags: vb.net

i will be grateful if somebody will explain to me why this code that i wrote is not executing on another thread (the code just executing Button4_Click sub without any exception). if i`m calling timerclass() sub from the main thread everything is running perfect.
i cant understand this behavior.. maybe i need to use delegate(?)

```
Private t As System.Threading.Thread
Private Sub Button4_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button4.Click
    t = New System.Threading.Thread(AddressOf timerclass)
    t.Start()
End Sub
Private TargetDT As DateTime
Private CountDownFrom As TimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(3)

Private Sub timerclass()
    tim = New Timer
    AddHandler tim.Tick, AddressOf tim_Tick
    tim.Interval = 500
    tim.Interval = 500
    TargetDT = DateTime.Now.Add(CountDownFrom)
    tim.Start()

End Sub

Private Sub tim_Tick(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs)
    Dim ts As TimeSpan = TargetDT.Subtract(DateTime.Now)
    If ts.TotalMilliseconds > 0 Then
        Label2.Text = ts.ToString("mm\:ss")
    Else
        Label2.Text = "00:00"
        tim.Stop()
        MessageBox.Show("Done")
    End If

End Sub
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Run timer in background thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6445957/run-timer-in-background-thread)

Comment: Why are you trying to run a thread inside a thread? Seems odd.